# How to create POD and use pod2usage in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I want to create a POD for my own custom command and display the syntax for that using pod2usage() function..

Can anyone give me a simple example for it?

Regards,
Anandan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do this using [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long) together with [Pod::Usage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pod::Usage). (I got into this habit after reading a tutorial on the PerlMonks site, so [here's the link to that](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=155288) as well.) It looks something like this example:

```
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;

my( $opt_help, $opt_man, $opt_full, $opt_admins, $opt_choose, $opt_createdb, );

GetOptions(
    'help!'                 =>      \$opt_help,
    'man!'                  =>      \$opt_man,
    'full!'                 =>      \$opt_full,
    'admin|admins!'         =>      \$opt_admins,
    'choose|select|c=s'     =>      \$opt_choose,
    'createdb!'             =>      \$opt_createdb,
)
  or pod2usage( "Try '$0 --help' for more information." );

pod2usage( -verbose => 1 ) if $opt_help;
pod2usage( -verbose => 2 ) if $opt_man;
```

The options other than `$opt_man` and `$opt_help` are irrelevant to you in that example. I just copied the top of a random script I had here.

After that, you just need to write the POD. Here's [a good link](http://juerd.nl/site.plp/perlpodtut) describing the basics of POD itself.

**Edit**: In response to the OP's question in the comments, here's how you might print just the `NAME` section when passed an appropriate option. First, add another option to the hash of options in `GetOptions`. Let's use `'name' => \$opt_name` here. Then add this:

```
pod2usage(-verbose => 99, -sections => "NAME") if $opt_name;
```

Verbose level 99 is magic: it allows you to choose one or more sections only to be printed. See the documentation of `Pod::Usage` under `-sections` for more details. Note that `-sections` (the name) is plural *even if you only want one section*.

Comment: thanks for the reply..that was useful.. but i have one more query here.
i want to print only the "NAME" section using this.. i dunno how to do that.can you help m  with that??

Comment: pod2usage(-section=>'NAME');  prints the NAME + other sections. this doesnt help me

Comment: @Anandan: I added an explanation about how to do this in the answer itself.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of good examples in the [perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) manpage. Pod2usage is explained [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html#pod2usage()).

Comment: I don't see pod2usage mentioned there, though ?

Comment: @Brian Agnew: Yes, you're right. I've edited my answer to link to pod2usage explanation and examples.